# Showing that an affine function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ has partial derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Fix $\mathbf{a}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbf{b}\in \mathbb{R}^m$. Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix with columns $\mathbf{a}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{a}_n$. Consider the affine function $\mathbf{f}: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ given by $\mathbf{x}\mapsto \mathbf{b}+A(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a})$.

I want to show that for every $\mathbf{c} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and every $j\in \{1, \ldots, n\}$, $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})$ is differentiable with respect to $x_j$ at $\mathbf{c}$ with $\mathbf{f}_{x_j}(\mathbf{c})=\mathbf{a}_j$.

NOTE: Our definition is that if the partial derivative exists, we have $\mathbf{f}_{x_j}(\mathbf{c})=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{c}+h\mathbf{e}_j)-\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{c}))$.

I don't see how to prove this from the definition. I'd appreciate if someone could show how the proof would go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that by linearity we have that $A(x+y) = A(x)+A(y)$ and $A(\alpha x) = \alpha A(x)$, for $\alpha \in \mathbb R$. Hence we have that:
\begin{align*}
 f(x+e_jh) -f(x) = b+A(x)+A(e_jh)-Aa -b - Ax +Aa = A(e_j h ) = h A(e_j) = h a_j. 
\end{align*}
Hence $\frac{f(x+e_jh) -f(x)}{h} = a_j$ and hence $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(x) = a_j.$